# How many strings of length 9 can be formed using the letters HELLOJELLO?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

This is a two part question, the first part was how many strings of length 10 can be formed using the letter HELLOJELLO?

For this half I got $\frac{10!}{4!2!2!}.$ What is the difference in the question if we go from $10$ length to $9,$ how does the approach in solving it change?

Comment: You should be able to convince yourself that there are exactly as many ways to pick a string of length 9 as there are to pick a string of length 10.  For a formal proof, consider making a bijection between the set of strings of length 9 and the set of strings of length 10 (*hint: given a string of length 9, there is only one unused letter left available to tack on to the end*)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to break up into cases:

- a $H$ is left out
- an $E$ is left out
- an $L$ is left out
- an $O$ is left out
- a $J$ is left out

Solve for each individual case, and doing that is the same as how you would do it before, but with $9$ letters instead of $10$

Answer (score 0):

> The problem here is that, as the letters are repeated here, you can't just do C(10 9). You have to deal with all the cases differently.

You have E,O and L repeated twice, twice and four times respectively. You have to account for all these letters separately in their own cases.

- H is left out
- one E is left out
- one L is left out
- one O is left out
- J is left out

Now you can sum all of these cases' answers and that'll be your final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do by encasing each situation, like H left out or J left out or E left out or L left out or O left out.

H and J have similar cases and so does E and O.

When H or J left out = 2 * 9! / (4! * 2! * 2!)
When E or O left out = 2 * 9! / (4! * 2!)
When L is left out = 9! / (3! * 2! * 2!)

So adding them all up would finally give us 9! / 3! as our answer